# How to make a UITableView cell dynamically change its height while user is typing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently working on a feature for dynamically changing a UITableView cell's height while typing. So, if the user has typed in a item that extends the current max width for a cell, then a the cell's height should increase. My specialized TableViewCell contains a TextView and an UILabel and is also, connected to another cell below it. So, there is a TableView with two TableViewCells within that one TableView. I've been trying to experiment ways that it could be solved but nothing has worked so far. Does anyone have any conceptual ideas to get it done?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far? Also, a quick search for `uitextview autosize height` comes up with lots of solutions.

Comment: Hey, I have tried out a few of those recommendations but my TableViewCell still doesn't expand as someone is typing and hits the max cell width amount. Usually, the online solutions talk about setting the TableView's `estimatedRowHeight` to a specific number and then setting the TableView's `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or `[.flexiblehHeight, .flexibleWidth]`. But, the individual cell within my TableView still doesn't want to expand. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you already gotten a `UITextView` to auto-size while typing, in just a plain view, not in a table view cell? If not, that's probably the best place to start. Get that working, and then adding it to a cell should be easy.

Comment: By the way... what code did you actually try? When I search for `uitextview autosize height` on google, the 4th result is this link - which is an article describing how to use a self-sizing Text View in a Table View Cell, including a link to an example app! (had to auto-convert from Swift 2 to 3, but that went without problem). So, here is the direct link: http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/

Answer (score 8):

First set your tableView rowHeight to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, in your table view cell add UITextView with top, leading, bottom and trailing constraints. Set `textView.isEditable` to `true` and `textView.isScrollEnabled` to `false`, then implement textView delegate method `textViewDidChange`. When text changes you need to report to view controller to update the tableview, one way is by delegation. Implement your table view cell delegate in your view controller, from where you'll call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`. That's it. Below is a tested and working example.

your view controller:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, ExpandingTableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExpandingTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExpandingTableViewCellIdentifier")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpandingTableViewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ExpandingTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    // Expanding teable view cell delegate
    func didChangeText(text: String?, cell: ExpandingTableViewCell) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

your cell:

```
import UIKit
protocol ExpandingTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func didChangeText(text: String?, cell: ExpandingTableViewCell)
}

class ExpandingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    weak var delegate: ExpandingTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.text = "Start typing: ..."
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        delegate?.didChangeText(text: textView.text, cell: self)
    }
}
```

Example project is here: https://github.com/bavarskis/ExpandingTableViewCell.git

Comment: Hey @Au Ris, Thanks for the solution but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I implemented the `didChangeText` function within the UITextViewDelegate for my specialized TableViewCell which contains a TextView and an UILabel, but the height of the cell still does not expand as someone types in content when the length reaches the width of the cell. Do you have any ideas of what could not be updating?

Comment: Get the example project and try to compare to your code: https://github.com/bavarskis/ExpandingTableViewCell.git

Comment: @AuRis - Tried the sample code but it's resizing ALL tableview cells, not just the cell the user is typing in...

Comment: The example only deals with one cell. What you experience is most likely the effect of cell reuse. You need to store the texts of each cell in view controller and update cells in cellForRowAt delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for a conceptual understanding of what’s going on you might want to look at a project in my github page:

https://github.com/mpj-chandler/variableSizeTextTableView

The project contains a subclassed UITableViewController controller that is also the delegate for the text views. The key functions are as follows:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    var textFrame : CGRect = textView.frame
    let newHeight : CGFloat = ceil(textView.contentSize.height)
    if newHeight - textFrame.height > 0 {
        textFrame.size.height = ceil(textView.contentSize.height)
        textView.frame = textFrame
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 5), animated: false)
        self.updateLayout(textView)
    }

    textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.characters.count, length: 0)
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func updateLayout(_ forTextView: UITextView) -> Void {
    guard forTextView.tag < self.data.count else { return }

    self.data[forTextView.tag] = forTextView.text

    let newHeight : CGFloat = forTextView.frame.height
    let oldHeight : CGFloat = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: forTextView.tag, section: 0))!.frame.height

    self.heights[forTextView.tag] = newHeight + 2
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
        for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row > forTextView.tag {
                    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y + forTextView.frame.height + 2 - oldHeight), size: CGSize(width: cell.frame.width, height: self.heights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]))
                }
                else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == forTextView.tag
                {
                    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: cell.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: cell.frame.width, height: self.heights[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]))
                }
            }
        }
    }) 
}
```

Caveats: this was written in Swift 2, but the translation to Swift 4 should be trivial. Also, it’s not a good idea to reference cells with tags if you want the table view to be editable, but hopefully you get the gist.

Hope it helps.